# Can someone identify this Brazilian bird?

Tags: species-identification, ornithology

Photographing and documenting the local fauna (Brasília, DF, Brazil - Near Coordinates [-15.696506 -47.860013]), I found this rather unusual-looking bird whose name I couldn't find:

---

[image: Two birds with long, kind of spiky-looking feathers on their heads, dark wing, beige-ish white chest and long tail feathers]

---

(Image was now uploaded to Wikimedia under my account "AlephGuira")

**Possibly useful information:**

- One was seen preying on
  what looked like *Taturanas* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lonomia), but due to their venomous nature, I'm not sure.
- The observed flock was composed of 7 birds.
- There seems to be sexual dimorphism (The other one, not pictured, seems to be smaller, has shorter head feathers, whiter wings and lacks the orange-pointed beak).
- They were first seen on a *Pequi* Tree (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caryocar_brasiliense).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

These look very similar to the Guira cuckoo (*Guira guira*) which are found in this part of Brazil.

[image]

Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guira_cuckoo